# Intuititions? WHY does Chi-squared Goodness-of-Fit really work?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, intuition

I have read through a few derivations for the Chi-square Goodness of Fit test, and I'd say I'm pretty happy with the maths (e.g. [this article](http://philassheton.blogs.lincoln.ac.uk/2016/11/06/chi-square-intuitions/) with its linked [derivation](http://philassheton.blogs.lincoln.ac.uk/2016/11/06/goodness-of-fit-derivation/)).  But, what I struggle with here, is that it still seems like magic to me or, at best, a happy coincidence, that when we divide the observed counts from our multinomial by $\sqrt{E}$ we get the magical covariance matrix

$\mathbf I - \sqrt{\mathbf p}\sqrt{\mathbf p}^T$ .

My question is -- is there any intuition about *why* we might expect this to happen??  Surely it's more than just happy coincidence, but I can't see any logic to it currently, other than just that, "when we do the maths it happens to work out".

Comment: It looks like the covariance matrix of residuals, see last equation in section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix#Overview

Comment: Thank you for the comment!  I agree, it is something I've been fascinated by is the geometric similarities between the goodness-of-fit test and linear models.  But where I'm stuck is understanding why dividing the outcomes of a multinomial by the square root of their expected values should happen to end up looking like this in the first place?